change device time and date without going to setting in android
i am working on android studio i made provision in my app to set date and time for that i need to open setting page , but i dont want to open another page from app i tried all way but cant set date and time of device without opening setting page from app.
i tried with DatePickerDialog and TimePickerDialog  by this graphics gets open but by that cant set date and time.                                                            `

Changing time and/or date requires a rooted device and root permissions for the app.

No, an Android app cannot directly update the system date and time. This action is restricted to maintain security and prevent app misuse.
Workable solution
Requesting the User to Manually Change Date/Time: You can guide users to the system settings where they can manually change the date and time.
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS)
startActivity(intent)

